# if statement in python, in jupyter Notebbok shows syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

if 5 == 15 / 3

File "", line 1
    if 5 == 15 / 3
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

--> it should display the true as as output.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you need to put a colon after the if conditional. Also, from a readability standpoint, I would recommend putting 5 == 15/3 in parentheses.

```
if(5 == 15/3):
    print(True)
```

For some more information on Python's conditionals, see [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).